# React.js: slice() twice and map()?

Tags: arrays, reactjs, object, split, jsx

My `useState()` should return a bold text (where there are * *stars* *) and line breaks (where there is a */n*).

So I thought of using `split()` and `map()`, but couldn't get the code to work properly when doing both:

```
let [abt, setAbt] = React.useState([]);
let abtTxt = `I have /n *stars* and /n *lines*`

setAbt(abtTxt.split('*')) // creating the bolded text
setAbt(abtTxt.split(/\n/)) // creating the line breaks

return (
   // bolding every two occasions:
      abt.map((boldSlice, i) => <span key={i} style={ i % 2 !== 0 ? {fontWeight: "bold"} : {} }> {boldSlice} </span>)
   // creating line breaks:
     .map(lineSlice => <> {lineSlice} <br/> </>)
 )
```

What should I do? Maybe something else like dangerous inner HTML?

**Thanks!**

Comment: The second call to setAbt will replace the results of the first call...

Comment: You could just use a markdown library.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```js
const LineComponent = ({line}) => {
  const style = index => ({fontWeight: index % 2 === 1 ? '700' : '400'});
  return (
    <span>{line.split('*').map((part, index) => (
      <span key={index} style={style(index)}>{part}</span>
    ))}
    </span>
  );
}

const TextComponent = ({str}) => {
  return (
    <div>
      {str.split(/\n/).map((line, index) => {
        return (
          <div key={index}>
            <LineComponent line={line}  />
            {index > 0 && <br/>}
          </div>
        );
      })}
    </div>
  );
}

ReactDOM.render(
  <TextComponent str={`I have \n *stars* and \n *lines*`} />,
  document.getElementById('container')
);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>

<div id="container">
</div>
```

Here is another one with no nested order of new line / bold delimiters:

```js
const TextComponent = ({str}) => {
const html = str.split('*').reduce((s, p, i) => `${s}${i % 2 === 1 ? `<b>${p}</b>` : p}`, '').replaceAll('\n', '<br/>');
return (<span dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{__html: html}} />);
} 

ReactDOM.render(
  <TextComponent str={`I have \n *stars and \n lin*es`} />,
  document.getElementById('container')
);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="container">
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do something like this

```
test = `I have /n *stars* and /n *lines*`;
test1 = test.split("/n");
test1.reduce((acc1, cur1) => {
  cur1 = cur1.split("*").reduce((a1, c1, i1) => {
    a1.push(
      <span key={i1} style={i1 % 2 !== 0 ? { fontWeight: "bold" } : {}}>
        c1
      </span>
    );
    return a1;
  }, []);
  acc1.push(...cur1, </br>);
  return acc1;
}, []);
```

Comment: There is an error: should be `<br/>` instead of `</br>`

Comment: Great idea, but it does not work when trying to break lines inside bolded text - the bolding only occur until the break: `I have /n *stars /n and /n lines*` would return *I have **stars** and lines*

Answer (score 1):

You can split with [capturing parentheses](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split#splitting_with_a_regexp_to_include_parts_of_the_separator_in_the_result), and then test each item, and format it accordingly:

```js
const bolden = /\*[^*]*\*/;
const lineBreak = /\/n/;
const all = new RegExp(`((?:${bolden.source}) | (?:${lineBreak.source}))`);

const removeAsterisks = str => str.replace(/\*/g, '')

const formatText = str => {
  let i = 0;
  
  return str.split(all)
    .map(s => {
      if(bolden.test(s)) return i++ % 2 ? removeAsterisks(s) : (
        <b>{removeAsterisks(s)}</b>
      );

      if(lineBreak.test(s)) return (<br />);

      return s;
    });
}

const Demo = ({ str }) => (
  <span>
    {
      formatText(str)
    }
  </span>
);

ReactDOM.render(
  <Demo str="I have /n *stars* and /n *lines*" />,
  root
);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>

<div id="root"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

you should never call a setState or useState setter in the render of a component.

you could write a simple function to do the work and use it in the render.

something like that:

```js
    const abtTxt = `I have /n *stars* and /n *lines*`;
    const abt = parseRawText(abtTxt);
```